# Как изменить шрифт в WebView

Tags: android, webview, шрифты

Получаю данные через гет запрос. Html неполный, т.е. не обрамлен тегами . Хочу заинжектить css, чтобы изменить шрифт. verdana.ttf скопировал в папку /assets. Но шрифт как был по дефолту, так и остался

```
String result = http.get("www.xxx.ru");; // Примерно   

htmlView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, getHtmlData(result), "text/html", "UTF-8", "");

   private String getHtmlData(String data){
        String head = "<head><style>@font-face {font-family: 'verdana';src: url('file:///android_asset/verdana.ttf');}body {font-family: 'verdana';}</style></head>";
        String htmlData= "<html>"+head+"<body>"+data+"</body></html>" ;
        return htmlData;
    }
```